# Configure XMonad Tall layout to expand all the way to the screen border

Tags: xmonad

I use the XMonad Tall layout and can expand and shrink the
master area with mod-l and mod-h.

Question: Is there a possibility to
to expand the master
area all the way to the border of the screen with one keystroke
 (instead of  having to press mod-l serveral times?). Something like a 
full-screen key combination. Is there then even a 
reverse key combinations to get out of full-screen mode again.
Does anyone know an example howto set this up?
I think I could use the Full layout for this, however I want to avoid
having to cycle though the layouts with mod-space. *How can I 
bind a keycombination to select a specific layout*? (i.e.  mod-shift-l to
cycle between  Full and Tall layout only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

To toggle between Full-Layout and a set of other layouts, in my case Tall and Tabbed, I did:

```
...
import XMonad.Layout.ToggleLayouts
...
myLayout =  avoidStruts (
    toggleLayouts Full (
                  Tall 1 (10/100) (2/3) |||
                  tabbed shrinkText tabConfig
                  )
    )
...

  -- Switch to Full layout.
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_l),
      sendMessage (Toggle "Full") )
```

Then, by pressing mod-shift-l Fullscreen Layout is enabled and reverted 
the next time mod-shift-l is pressed.
Snippet from https://gist.github.com/jianingy/5472640 , I dont
have the slightest clue how Haskell works...